# _closure and _info symbols in ghc dynamic libraries

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, dynamic-linking

I'm wondering why some _closure symbols do not have corresponding _info symbols.

On OSX I have installed ghc-7.8.3 via https://ghcformacosx.github.io/

If I run:

```
nm -gU /Applications/ghc-7.8.3.app/Contents/lib/ghc-7.8.3/bin/../directory-1.2.1.0/libHSdirectory-1.2.1.0-ghc7.8.3.dylib | grep findExecut
```

I get the following output:

```
0000000000010348 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable1_closure
000000000000a3a8 T _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable1_info
000000000000fe90 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable2_closure
000000000000fe78 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable3_closure
000000000000fe58 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable4_closure
00000000000046c8 T _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable4_info
00000000000105a8 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable_closure
000000000000d6f0 T _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutable_info
0000000000010338 D _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutablezuzdsa_closure
000000000000a030 T _directoryzm1zi2zi1zi0_SystemziDirectory_findExecutablezuzdsa_info
```

Note that not all of the _closure symbols have corresponding _info symbols.

I have a situation where tar-0.4.1.0 is referencing the findExecutable3_info symbol, and linking fails because it isn't found. But first I'd like to understand the why and wherefores of the _info symbols.

Answer (score 3):

See this diagram of a closure from https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects:

[image: layout of a closure]

Every ordinary ("boxed") Haskell value is represented in memory by an object called a closure. The first word of the closure is called the "info pointer" and identifies what sort of value it is, while the rest of the closure contains data that determines the specific value (for instance, the fields of an ADT). Most closures are dynamically allocated on the heap, but a compiled Haskell program can also contain so-called static closures in its data sections. The `_closure` symbols are these closures that live inside the object file, and the `_info` symbols are the pointers to the end of info tables and the start of entry code.

For instance, if your program contains the source

```
x :: Integer
x = 123
```

then it will be compiled into the core

```
x :: Integer
x = S# 123#     -- S# is the "small integer" constructor for Integer,
                -- and 123# is an unboxed Int# literal
```

and in the object file there will be a symbol with a name like `x_closure` which is two words long, whose first word points to `S#_info` (via an ELF relocation) and whose second word is the value 123. In this case, there is no need for an `x_info` because `x` is an `S#` value.

For a function `f`, GHC will generate both an `f_info` which can be called directly when `f` is used in a context in which it is supplied enough arguments, and an `f_closure` with info pointer `f_info` which can be used otherwise (for example if `f` is used as an argument to a higher-order function). See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#FunctionClosures.

As for your linker error, you probably have some interface files that are out of sync with their corresponding object files. There is no particular meaning to the name `findExecutable3`, it's just some auxiliary definition that got lifted to the top level when compiling `findExecutable`. I would guess that somewhere in the interface file for `System.Directory` (or a module which depends on it) you have some unfolding that refers to a function `findExecutable3`, but when `System.Directory` was compiled, `findExecutable3` actually ended up being some other sort of value.